# D3 force layout binding by reference getting out of sync

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, javascript-objects

I have a force layout to which I'm dynamically adding nodes.

TL;DR: My graph's data binding seems to be getting out of sync between the nodes and the links.  Are there any examples of setting up a force graph with dynamic addition and subtraction of nodes **using object references** rather than IDs or name?

All the examples I've seen use IDs to map nodes and links, but the documents say (emphasis added):

> Note: the values of the source and target attributes **may** be initially
>   specified as indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by
>   references after the call to start.

In my case, I have a Node class and a Link class that embodies the nodes and links.  The links have actual references to the nodes, and so I *assume* I don't have to do anything more to associate the nodes and the links.

The force network is doing its thing in laying out a network.  But it appears that the nodes at a given link.source and link.target are not the nodes that that are supposed to be there, leading me to thing my assumptions about d3 binding are incorrect.  Am I failing to set (or reset) some global state in the force mechanism?

My graph update code is along these lines:

```
GraphView.prototype.updateGraph = function(graph) {
var graph_view = this;

// restart the force layout
this.force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links);

// update the links
this.link_selection = this.link_selection.data(graph.links);
this.link_selection.exit().remove();
this.link_selection.enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link");

// update the nodes
this.node_selection = this.node_selection.data(graph.nodes);
this.node_selection.exit().remove();
var node_enter = this.node_selection.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on('mouseover', this._showTooltip.bind(this))
    .on('mouseout', this._hideTooltip.bind(this))
    .on('click', this._selectNode.bind(this))
    .on('mousedown', this._handleMouseDown.bind(this))
    .on("contextmenu", function(data, index) { graph_view._showContextMenu(data, index); })
    .call(this.force.drag);

// create outer circle
node_enter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "annulus")
    .style('fill', function(d) { return graph_view.nodeColor(d); })
    .style('r', function(d) { return graph_view.nodeRadius(d); })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

// start ticking...
this.force.start();
};
```

The tick method:

```
GraphView.prototype._tick = function(e) {
this.link_selection
    .attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    var dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M " + d.source.x + " " + d.source.y +
        " A " + dr + " " + dr + " 0 0 1 "
        + d.target.x + " " + d.target.y;
    });
this.node_selection
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')' });
};
```

Comment: I fear this line `this.link_selection.data(graph.links);` is incorrect when you use `this.link_selection.exit().remove()` there should be a way to uniquely identify a data with a DOM. It should have been this
`this.link_selection.data(graph.links, function(d){return UNIQUE_ID_FOR_DATA});`

Comment: @Cyril: thank you.  But isn't the object reference itself unique? I could see how a piece of memory that gets GC'd and then reused for another node would cause trouble if the force layout cached state, but I'm re-establishing the link/node association in line 5 of #updateGraph().  Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Yeah the reference is unique but how will it compare two JSON objects...how will it know which nodes to remove on update. That is the reason why you may have to give a unique string for comparing so that d3 knows the dataset present and the new dataset you providing. And based on that exit() selection will give the dom that need to removed

Comment: Have you seen this question: [*"Adding new nodes to Force-directed layout"*](/q/9539294)?

Comment: Yes I have, along with the http://bl.ocks.org/1095795 demo.  Note that I re-associate the links and nodes at the beginning of each call to #updateGraph().  But I'll have to mull over @Cyril's comments before coming to any rash conclusions.

Comment: also in your example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 you will find this  _link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });_ where he is giving unique id to the link data...This is what you are missing in your code, assuming that the object reference will do the trick but i know it will not :)

Comment: I should add this to the O.P., but the docs explicitly say "Note: the values of the source and target attributes MAY be initially specified as indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by references after the call to start." (emphasis mine...)

Comment: Read this [part of the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data), if a **key** funciton is not specified `d3` is calculating enter, exit and update **based on index alone**.

Comment: Mark - make that an answer and earn a check (unless @Cyril beats you to it).  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what's going on.

First, the reason I haven't seen any examples of using object references for d3.layout.force is because it won't work: the mechanism that associates links and nodes requires that each link and each node provide an immutable handle, i.e. an id.  (Yes, you can use array indexes, but that's a different question).

The slightly surprising thing is that the immutable handle can be anything, as long as it is unique to its corresponding node or link.  In fact, there doesn't need to be any relationship between the node id and the link id -- these are only used when setting up the array indexes.

I hope someone provides a more complete answer so I can award a checkmark.  But if they don't, I'll try to provide a more complete description of what's going on.  It's a little magic, but not *entirely* magic.